# Why there should be an x in .issubset(x) while using this lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm following a tutorial and it has this code. I understood why I have used `set()` but I don't get the use of putting an `X` in `issubset()`. Is the last `x` representing that I'm subsetting first `x` i.e. `lambda x:`?
Kindly help.

```
lambda_x = lambda x: set(['Romance','Comedy', 'Action', 
'Thriller']).issubset(x)
```

Comment: As a side note, I don't know what tutorial you're following, but you might want to find a better one. This is (a) an abuse of `lambda` that makes it look like the author would rather be using Lisp than Python, and (b) a potentially confusing question for a pretty contrived scenario.

Answer (score 3):

`lambda_x` is a function that determines if its argument is a superset of the hard-coded set of genres. This is would be better written as

```
def lambda_x(x):
    return set(['Romance', 'Comedy', 'Action', 'Thriller']).issubset(x)
```

(A `lambda` expression defines an anonymous function. If you're going to assign it a name, use the `def` statement.)

Even better, just define the bound method. (In functional programming, this is called point-free style.)

```
lambda_x = set(['Romance', 'Comedy', 'Action', 'Thriller']).issubset
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just call `s.issubset()`, that's like the English question "Is `s` a subset of?" Which obviously has no answer, because it's not a well-formed question. A subset of *what*?

"Is `s` a subset of the thing that got passed to this function?" makes a lot more sense. And in Python, since `x` is the thing that got passed to this function (from the `lambda x:`), that's just `s.issubset(x)`.

---

The use of `lambda` here probably makes things more confusing. And this function shouldn't use `lambda` in the first place. The entire point of `lambda` is that you can use it in the middle of an expression, and you don't have to give the defined function a name. If you want to define a function with a name, in a statement, that's what `def` is for.

And `def` gives us the freedom to rewrite things a bit less tersely:

```
def romcomactionthriller(genres):
    rcat_genres = set(['Romance','Comedy', 'Action', 'Thriller'])
    return rcat_genres.issubset(genres)
```

So, you take a parameter that's a set of genres, and you want to know if `rcat_genres` is a subset of that set. So you can do this:

```
if romcomactionthriller(movie.list_genres()):
    print('Found a movie we can all enjoy')
    return movie
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is testing that the RCAT (Romance, Comedy, Action, Thriller) set is a subset of `x`. That is

```
lambda_x(['Comedy', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Thriller', 'Sci-Fi'])
```

is

```
True
```

while

```
lambda_x(['Comedy', 'Romance', 'Action'])
```

is

```
False
```

This seems like a contrived example. For a pedagogical example, consider

```
square_x = lambda x: x * x
square_x(2) # 4
square_x(3) # 9
```

Also, you can name it something besides `x`.

```
cube = lambda y: y * y * y
cube(2) # 8
```

Answer (score 1):

lambda_x is the function name. And if you want to call it you need to pass a parameter x, x should be a set. The lambda_x will return the bool value that whether set(['Romance','Comedy', 'Action', 'Thriller']) is a subset of the set "x" you passed

```
lambda_x = lambda x: set(['Romance','Comedy', 'Action', 'Thriller']).issubset(x)
lambda_x(set(['Romance','Comedy']))
>>>>False
lambda_x(set(['Romance','Comedy','Romance','Comedy', 'Action', 'Thriller']))
>>>>True
```

I am not sure whether this can make it clear to understand.